# Why WSO2 Registry wouldn't store my chinese characters?

Tags: character-encoding, wso2

I ran a WSO2 Registry server to maintain our configurations. It played its role perfectly, until one day I put some Chinese characters into resource content.
I created a resource with 'Create Text Content', and Chinese characters into both 'Description' and 'Content' fields. When I opened this resource again, the 'Description' field remained Chinese, but the 'Content' text became a sequence of '?'(question marks, one Chinese character each).
Why would this happen, and how to prevent it?

Comment: Could you tell me which governance registry version you are using?  Are you getting any exceptions in back-end console while saving resource content with Chinese characters?

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact version number. I installed it through Carbon 4 online repository. No exception stack trace is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start the Governance Registry with the "carbon.registry.character.encoding" system property.

Please see more details in documentation [1].

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/Supported+System+Properties

Eg :

sh wso2server.sh -Dcarbon.registry.character.encoding={chinese encoding type}

Comment: Yes, this works great. But when I use "wso2server.sh start" to start a s daemon, I cannot find the way to set this. I read the script and find that the daemon.sh does not accept extra properties. I put this property into the wrapper.conf file as "wrapper.java.additional.13=-Dcarbon.registry.character.encoding=utf-8" and it still does not work. Am I missing something, or what I did was completely wrong?